# What's the differences between android_support_v7.jar and support_v7 source code?

Tags: android, android-support-library

It's confusing that some classes appears in support_v7.jar but not in the source code. For example, `android.support.v7.app.AlertController`. Why does this happen? And where can I find the source codes of these missing classes?

Comment: You can find source code here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java

Comment: @PareshMayani The version of AlertController in support v7 library is different from the version from android internal package.